# Broken MP4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, data-recovery, mp4

So I was filming with my phone (Nokia 6.2) and one of the video files was corrupted because the storage of the sd-card was full after almost 20 minutes. The file is about 4 GB, but doesn't work. I already tried Wondershare video repair and other softwares I could find (with and without a reference video). The only one that seems to work is mp4repair.org (without a reference video), but they charge over 60 dollars for the single video. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to repair the corrupt video with
[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html),
as follows:

1. Launch VLC, enter menu *Media > Convert or Save*
2. Click *Add* to add the broken input file and press *Convert / Save*
3. In the Convert window that appears, provide the destination file name
   and select the desired Codec from the profile list
4. Press *Start* to save or convert.